# Glide library incompatibility with v7:26.1.0

Tags: android

I am trying to add Glide library in my project but I am facing problem while compiling the Gradle. By the way I'm facing the same problem with Picasso.

Comment: Are you using `Glide v4`? And what do you mean `incompatibility`, is `build.gradle` show any warning?

Comment: give us grandle files

Comment: @Lhex please paste grandle code so we can help you.

Comment: these are somme bugs or responses that I have every time that I am trying to compile the Gradle: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0.  or Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1.

Comment: Here us my Gradle Code:   
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'

}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your files for glide be like:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
}
```

Or for picasso make sure you are using the latest version:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```